# SciKit-Learn - Predicting factors that make the most change

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I just watched a 3 hour long intro to SciKit-Learn, and I understand the basics of the regression models, supervised and un-supervised learning, etc. These models are great for predicting results based on a set of input data. But is there a method where I can say that, say, I have 20 products and a massive log of sells with multiple data (like time, price, category and so on), and I want to know which 3 product prices to change to increase the profit the most?

The KPI is how much profit I make (net profit per product sold times quantity sold), and I want to improve the pricing model. So I change 3 products, and I want to teach a model to tell me which 3 product prices should I increase/decrease to achieve the highest profit increase.

In short:
Is there a model in SciKit-Learn (or in general, like, a mathematical model), that I can tell to change a certain number of data, and it will give me those that have the most impact on the results?

I figured I could teach a Random Forest or just a simple regression with my data, then write a function to iterate through changing 3 prices at a time, predict the data and find the best result, but I think this would be very costly, since basically I'd have to iterate through every variaton of products. And then there's also the question of the amount of change in price, whether it should be positive or negative, etc. So I have a feeling that there's a better way, I just haven't figured it out yet.

Do you have any ideas? Does SciKit have anything like this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I would say that machine learning is a bit overkill for what you're doing.

Profit = p1*q1 + p2*q2 + ... pn*qn

where pn, qn are the price, quantity of the nth product.

You can independently determine the optimum price for each product by finding the point along your price vs. quantity curves that maximize profit for each item. (I suppose you could use [gradient descent](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/sgd.html) for this part). From here, you can determine which current product prices are farthest from their optimum price, and change the ones that result in the largest profit.